# Unsure of what to add to hosts file - Apache Subdomain

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm trying to make a subdomain for my xampp/apache hosted website.
However, whenever I attempt to access the subdomain it gives me an "HTTPS insecure error" and redirects me to the main part of the site. Also, I can still access the main site without any issues at all.

In my 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file, I believe all the entries are correct and the issue lies with my hosts file.

To clarify, this is a website with a premium domain name, (i.e not just a website for local use). Most of the tutorials and guides I can find are only really designed for websites that are used locally only.

Here is my 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file (with my domain name edited out of course):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName domain.xyz
    ServerAlias https://domain.xyz
    ErrorLog "logs/domain.xyz-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.xyz-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sub1"
    ServerName sub1.domain.xyz
    ServerAlias https://sub1.domain.xyz
    ErrorLog "logs/sub1.domain.xyz-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/sub1.domain.xyz-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The entries I have in my hosts file are (which I'm fairly certain is completely wrong):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   domain.xyz
127.0.0.1   sub1.domain.xyz
```

Comment: Don't put the scheme (https) in the ServerAlias

Comment: After removing it still provides the same result; redirecting me to the main site.

Comment: Add NameVirtualHost *:80 above the VirtualHost entries

Comment: Still the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Did you reload Apache?

Comment: Yep. Each time I edit the vhosts file I restart the apache service.

Comment: You don't have the subdomain as a ServerAlias in both VirtualHosts do you?  The subdomain is a VirtualHost, not an alias for the main domain (in this case).

Comment: In my 2nd VirtualHost I have sub1.domain.xyz as my ServerAlias. And in my 1st VirtualHost (for my main site) I have the ServerAlias as domain.xyz

Comment: You should have two VirtualHosts, each with a different ServerName and no aliases.

Comment: Just removed the ServerAlias' and received the same result. Seeing as how it's redirecting to the main site whenever I go to the subdomain, I'm still thinking it might be my hosts file.

Comment: Posted onto pastebin because formatting http://pastebin.com/saG56DqA

And yes, there is an .htaccess file.